# SQL Server DENSE_RANK returns wrong result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to select the latest file in the `taskID`.

The id needs to change only when task or filenumber changes.

The file which has higher `HistoryID` should get id of 1, and subsequent files 2+.

Here is the current code, it's ranking when `historyID` changes as well. Last column is what I need:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY taskid, filenumber 
                   ORDER BY HISTORYID DESC) AS id_file_to_keep
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, as images of data don't help us help you (I can't copy text out of an image), however, perhaps this is what you want:

```sql
WITH Mins AS(
    SELECT taskid,
           historyID,
           filenumber,
           MIN(historyID) OVER (PARTITION BY taskid, filnumber) AS minHistoryID
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT taskid,
       historyID,
       filenumber,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY taskid ORDER BY minHistoryID DESC) AS DesiredID
FROM Mins;
```

Comment: Thanks, Larnu. I changed min to max as it's more intuitive, and it worked. Your answer's been accepted gracefully. Just out of curiosity, isn't there no way to get it done without a CTE then?

Comment: You can't wrap a windowed aggregate inside a windowed aggregate, no @LanaB, so you would need to use a CTE or subquery.